# C++ Ignore Empty First Line

Tags: c++, file-io, blank-line

How do I ignore an empty first line in "input.txt"? I don't necessarily know that there is an empty line (in this particular case there is, but I want to make my code generic), so I need to be able to read the line if there is information, or skip it if it is blank. This is just for the first line.

```
while (getline(mcFile, line)) { 
    istringstream liness2(line); ... }
```

That's how I'm reading the lines. If I knew for certain that any input file I ran this on had an empty first line, I would just do "getline" before, but I don't know that.

Comment: You'll get a better response if you post your existing code.

Comment: also.. you should check if it is the first line and if it's blank. If those two conditions succeed, skip it...

Comment: `while (getline(mcFile, line))
{
    istringstream liness2(line);
    ...
}`

That's how I'm reading the lines. If I knew for certain that any input file I ran this on had an empty first line, I would just do "getline" before, but I don't know that.

Comment: @user1187621: how do you read from `liness2`?  That's the part that should detect if the line is empty or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
string data;

while (getline(inputFile, data))
{
    if (data == "") continue; // Skip blank line

    ... // Do stuff with non-blank line
}
```

Comment: But if the line consists only of whitespaces, tabs and so on?

Comment: Make a temporary copy of data and parse whitespace out of it before checking if it's blank.

Answer (score 0):

```
ifstream ReadFile;
ReadFile.open("input.txt");
string content;
string line;

 if (myReadFile.is_open()) {
     while (!ReadFile.eof()) {

        getline(cin,line);

        content += line + '\n';
        if (!line.empty()) {
            /// do what you want to do
        }
     }
  }
```